# How to find a directory in a linux server is whether shared across many servers or not?

Tags: linux

How to find a directory in a linux server  is whether shared across many servers (common mount) or not?

Answer (score 0):

`mount -l | grep 'type nfs' | sed 's/.* on \([^ ]*\) .*/\1/'` should give you a list of all nfs mountpoints on the system, then you can grep your dir name:

```
mount -l | grep 'type nfs' | sed 's/.* on \([^ ]*\) .*/\1/' | grep /path/to/dir
```